# Heat switch material

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

Sort of a general question, but does there exist or might there exist a sort of thermal switching material? A material that could be switched from a thermal insulator (maybe more of a thermal insulator than air) to a thermal conductor by some means like through electricity, light or magnetism? Kind of like a thermal switch? It would be a useful material a device had to remain hot or cool off quickly, without using a fan.

Comment: not quite what you are asking but look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling

Comment: I found some high-level stuff about using phase transitions or magnetic properties to achieve changing thermal conductivity, but I feel like there are more reasonable ways without exotic materials to do what you want.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I was thinking that it could be used for a phase changing material/alloy.  It could thermally insulate the phase change material so that it could remain in a higher temperature phase with less energy being wasted.  Then it could be switched to a conductive form so that the material could revert to the lower temperature phase.